# Python Redis stream xread with "$"

Tags: python, redis

Does Python redis not support `"$"`?  The following will not return a record when the stream is updated.

`redis.xread(streams={"stream_name": "$"}, count=None, block=0)`

Comment: I think you should have written `{"stream" : "$"}`.  The argument is supposed to be a dictionary, not a set.

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo.  I have corrected it.  Thanks for noting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this definitely works, it will only return something if the stream has a new entry added AFTER running the code.

```py
import redis

r = redis.Redis(host="localhost", port=6379, decode_responses=True)

response = r.xread(
  streams = {
    "mystream": "$"
  },
  count=None,
  block=0
)

print(response)
```

Run the code:

```
$ python app.py
```

Then in `redis-cli`:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> xadd mystream * n 1
"1694185661724-0"
```

Code will immediately return:

```
[['mystream', [('1694185661724-0', {'n': '1'})]]]
```

Now in redis-cli:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> xadd mystream * n 2
"1694185942369-0"
```

Now run the code again and nothing will happen (as expected, as `$` is the ID for entries added since we started blocking:

> When blocking sometimes we want to receive just entries that are added to
> the stream via XADD starting from the moment we block.

https://redis.io/commands/xread/

If you want to pick up from where you left off from the previous run of the code, you'll need to persist the last entry ID read from the stream and supply that as the argument to `XREAD` - this will then give you the next entry added to the stream since your last one, regardless of whether your code was running when that entry was added.

Additionally, you don't need `count=None` - I'd recommend passing in an actual number here e.g. `1`.

Note, when I'm connecting to Redis I'm using `decode_responses=True` which will make redis-py decode the byte arrays to more useful Python types e.g. strings in this case.

requirements.txt:

```
async-timeout==4.0.3
redis==5.0.0
```

Python version:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.10.7
```